# Max retries exceeded (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

Tags: django, python-requests

I'm getting an error `max retries exceeded and 403 forbidden` but when I run server on localhost it's working perfectly fine. I'm showing data from an API in django template I also tried to turn off validation and keep alive sessions but nothing intersting happened I'm getting same error

my code:

```
def index(request):
    try:
        url = "https://www.hetzner.com/a_hz_serverboerse/live_data.json"
        s = requests.session()
        s.keep_alive = False
        r = requests.post(url, verify=False, timeout=5)

        data = response.json()['server']
        p = Paginator(data, 20)
        pn = request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = p.get_page(pn)
        context = {
            'data': data,
            'page_obj': page_obj
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)


    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        return HttpResponse({e})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then the server you are using doesn't have an outgoing Internet connection or there is a proxy that you need to configure in your code so you can reach the internet, this is an infrastructure issue and not and a software development issue, so you need to check with Admin and/or provider support.